# How to make a div stick beside a checkbox and label?

Tags: html, css

This is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/TX8fs/1/

I tried

```
display:block;float:left;
```

But the urgent input checkbox will overlap the 2 input infront of it. Any solution to fix this? I want to display the urgent input checkbox beside the label.

Comment: Your questions needs a [mcve]. Don't make us visit a third party site when you can easily embed a code example in your question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TX8fs/2/)

Note: only switched order of HTML elements inside div, and added "float: left;" to **

```css
.select-style{
    display: inline;
}

.onoffswitch {
        position: relative; width: 136px;
        -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
        float: left; /* ** added line ** */
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label {
        display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 0px;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner {
        display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
        transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 19px; padding: 0; line-height: 15px;
        font-size: 12px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid transparent;

    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:before {
        content: "URGENT";
        padding-left: 10px;
        background-color: #FF0000; color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        content: "URGENT";
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #000000;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .onoffswitch-switch {
        display: block; width: 12px; margin: 0px;
        background: #A1A1A1;
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        right: 124px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
        right: 0px;
        background-color: #A1A1A1;
    }
```

```html
   <!--Text box -->
      <input data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#b" type="checkbox">
                        <label class="label-supplier"> abc&nbsp; </label>
 
        <!-- dropdown menu -->
        <div class="select-style">
           <div class="onoffswitch">
                        
                        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="#a">
                            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                        </label>
                        <!-- Switch order of checkbox and switch-->
                        <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox btn-urgent" id="#a">
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Extra explanation: your original idea was correct but in order to make the switch "float" next to the checkbox, it must be order correctly as well. Think of the order just like as you would read the elements in a list (from left to right = corresponds to from top to bottom in the html order).

Comment: I want to show behind the label instead infront of the checkbox. But when i switch order, the urgent checkbox will overlap the others.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to simply make your `.select-style` an `inline-block` instead of an `inline` element, as can be seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ggj33de/)**.

```css
.select-style {
  display: inline-block;
}

.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 136px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 19px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "URGENT";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "URGENT";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #A1A1A1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 124px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #A1A1A1;
}
```

```html
<!--Text box -->
<input data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#b" type="checkbox">
<label class="label-supplier"> abc&nbsp; </label>

<!-- dropdown menu -->
<div class="select-style">
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox btn-urgent" id="#a">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="#a">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if you additionally want to ensure that all three elements are aligned vertically, you'll need to also add `vertical-align: middle` to all three elements:

```
input, input + label, .select-style {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Which results in the following:

```css
.select-style {
  display: inline-block;
}

.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 136px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 19px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "URGENT";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "URGENT";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #A1A1A1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 124px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #A1A1A1;
}

input, input + label, .select-style {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!--Text box -->
<input data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#b" type="checkbox">
<label class="label-supplier"> abc&nbsp; </label>

<!-- dropdown menu -->
<div class="select-style">
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox btn-urgent" id="#a">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="#a">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: In my case, it is not working, i have no idea why, it will overlapping my checkbox and label

Comment: In my example it is working. You may need to `clear` some of your `floats`. Can you please provide an MVCE with it not working?

Comment: Yeah, it is working in example, i have tried every working example, but in my display it keep overlapping the label.

Comment: @ObsidianAge This is why you should never answer questions that don't supply the markup and code inside the question itself and use third party sources.

Comment: @Rob Well, i am using exactly same code, and it is just not displaying well, what should i do with it? Is okay, i will figure it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Zidance As you were told in the comments under your question and flagged for closure, **you are to supply all markup that shows the problem in the question itself.** When you use jsfiddle instead, you will be flagged for closure every single time because jsfiddle, and other such sites, will add markup or code that can affect how it works. Additionally, such third party sites can change or disappear making the whole question or answer useless in the future.